# PHP Mail blank emails

Tags: php, email

I have  a loop of different destinations to send a couple of emails. When I send them one by one (breaking the for-each) the mail sends successfully. When I allow the for-each to send all mails in the loop several of the emails arrive blank...

Why does trying to send multiple emails form the for-each loop result in blank emails?

```
foreach ($facturas as $factura) {
    $para = "";
    $cabeceras = "";
    $mensaje = "";
    $título = "";

        $query = "SELECT *,u.email as email_usuario,u.nombre usu_nombre,u.apellido usu_apellido,e.nombre evento_nombre,
                    e.fecha evento_fecha,o.nombre op_nombre,c.nombre cat_nombre
                    FROM facturas 
                    INNER JOIN inscribite_eventos e ON e.codigo = fac_evento_id
                    INNER JOIN inscribite_opciones o ON o.id = fac_op_id AND o.evento = fac_evento_id
                    INNER JOIN inscribite_categorias c ON c.deevento = fac_evento_id AND c.codigo = fac_cat_id
                    INNER JOIN inscribite_usuarios u ON u.id = fac_usu_id
                    WHERE fac_id = {$factura['fac_id']}";
        $inscripcion = getRowQuery($query, $mysqli);

        if (!empty($mysqli->error)) {
            throw new Exception('Fallo trayendo datos' . $query . '<br>' . $mysqli->error);
        }

        //$para = ' '.$inscripcion['usu_nombre'].' '.$inscripcion['usu_apellido'].' <'.$inscripcion['email_usuario'].'>'; // con coma si son más
        $para = 'dedieu92g@gmail.com';
        // título
        $título = 'Confirmacion de Pago Inscribite Online';
        // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
        $cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

        // Cabeceras adicionales
        //$cabeceras .= 'To: Usuario <'.$inscripcion['email_usuario'].'>' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <info@inscribiteonline.com.ar>' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras .= 'Cc: Recordatorio <info@inscribiteonline.com.ar>' . "\r\n";       

        if ($inscripcion['tipo'] == 'Deportivos') {
            require_once 'mail_deportivos.php';
        }
        elseif ($inscripcion['tipo'] == 'Servicios') {
            require_once 'mail_servicios.php';
        }
        elseif ($inscripcion['tipo'] == 'Productos') {
            require_once 'mail_productos.php';
        }
        elseif ($inscripcion['tipo'] == 'CapacitaciÃ³n') {
            require_once 'mail_capacitacion.php';
        }


        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

        // Enviarlo
        if(mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras)){
            $query = "UPDATE facturas_pagas SET facp_avisado = 1 WHERE facp_fac_id = {$inscripcion['fac_id']}";
            runQuery($query,$mysqli);

            //echo $mensaje;
            //die('mando con factura'.$inscripcion['fac_id']);
        }
        sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: You never give a value to `$mensaje`

Comment: You set `$mensaje = ""` at the start of the loop, and never add a value to it.

Comment: sorry, inside of each require_once mail:capacition or productos or... then i set the mensaje var

Comment: the strange thing is when i make it one by one with the same code all works perfectly but when i run the script free, is like a time thing... the first always arrives then the 5th.. then the 11th.. maybe a time delay for multiple mails?

Comment: @GDedieu - `require_once()` will include the file, once. The second time through your loop, your code won't be run. You might be able to use `include()` instead, but without knowing what the code is, I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks andrewsi, you were right. THe problem was that i used the require_once through the loop and when the next cicle of the loop arrives, the var mensaje never fill again cause the code was already required.

I replace the require_once for an include and all works perfectly =)

Thanks a lot!